# Brave browser how to turn off autosuggest in Address bar

Tags: browser, autocomplete, autosuggest, brave

When I type a web address Brave suggest really stupid websites. Example: when I just type 'mu' it suggests 'elmundo.es'. If I type 'po' it suggests 'huffingtonpost.com'

I have never visited these sites, it's not in my bookmarks, my history is 100% cleared and the two settings regarding 'prediction services' are both turned off. I have restarted my browser.

This feature is very, very annoying. Can I install an extension that removes this auto-suggest, or am I the only one getting mad from this??? :-). Besides this the Brave Browser seems like a good choice.

Thanks in advance

JonasM

Answer (score 2):

Search "top sites" in Brave settings and disable this:

[image]